# Firestore how to combine orderBy desc with startAfter(null)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've been searching for this one for a while but have not found a reason why this is the way it is.

Basically this returns an array of documents in the collection.

```
this.db.collection('people', ref => {
    return ref.orderBy(name, 'asc')
              .startAfter(null)
              .limit(10)
})...
```

This returns an empty array.

```
this.db.collection('people', ref => {
    return ref.orderBy(name, 'desc')
              .startAfter(null)
              .limit(10)
})...
```

The only difference is orderBy is set to 'desc'.  Can someone please explain why this happens and a way around it?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is `startAfter(null)`. When you sort in ascending order, the null docs come first and then the non-null docs. For the exact order, see the [Firebase documentation on the ordering of value types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering).

When you sort in descending order, all the null docs come last so there is nothing after the null docs for the query to return.

I suggest removing `startAfter(null)` until you have a value for it.

Comment: If I remove startAfter my snapshotChanges fires twice for some reason.  Not sure why

Comment: Is it firing twice after a write operation? Local writes fire twice, once locally and then again when the write is committed to the database. See the docs on [latency compensation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).

Comment: Not writes just reads.  SnapshotChanges fires twice when I apply a where query to the collection.  It looks like it first emits some cached values and then the complete response from the server.

Comment: Hope this answer helped. Do you have another question about SnapshotChanges? If so, please post another question with a snippet showing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone interested with my solution just arrow up:

```
var lastDocumentSnapshot : DocumentSnapshot? = null;
if (url != null){
    val query = this.getLastDocumentSnapshotAsync(url).await()
     if (!query.isEmpty){
        lastDocumentSnapshot = query.documents.distinct().first()
     }
}

val query = firebaseDb.collection("urls")
    .orderBy("name", sortDirection)
    .limit(limit)
if (sortDirection == Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    query.startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshot)
else
    query.endBefore(lastDocumentSnapshot)

return query.get().asDeferredAsync()
```

Don't mind the other parts of the code. basically the fix is to use `endBefore` if the sort is descending.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand your code. It does not make good sense to me. But the ```endBefore``` trick worked dor descending order though. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, your code does not directly answer the question asked. For those who are new to the subject, they'll get confused. I got my solution working just by using ```endBefore``` instead of ```startAfter``` like you suggested. That alone should be your answer.